# How to obtain CURDATE() / NOW() on a JPA named query?

Tags: java, date, jpa

I want to do a select from table where date = TODAY, on mysql that would be `where date > CURDATE()`, how do I do this on a JPA named query?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That depends on your JPA provider. Hibernate, for example, supports [current_date](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-standardized-functions) function:

```
from MyEntity where myDateProperty > current_date
```

Comment: The edit removed the brackets but actually, I needed them on my query (JPA 2.2, Intellij JPA query console). Otherwise it expects `current_date` to be column.

Answer (score 47):

From the [spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=220):

> 4.6.16.3 Datetime Functions
>
> ```
> functions_returning_datetime:=
> CURRENT_DATE |
> CURRENT_TIME |
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> ```
>
> The datetime functions return the
>   value of current date, time, and
>   timestamp on the database server.

Comment: Regarding the fact that `CURRENT_DATE` is a standard JPA function and it should work the same way across all JPA providers and RDBMS, it causes error in Hibernate with SQL Server and should be used as  `CURRENT_DATE()` instead. So the @chssply76's answer is also correct: _"That depends on your JPA provider."_

Comment: @naXa - CURRENT_DATE - 1 doesn't works nor YESTERDAY? How to achieve this?

Comment: @JeffCook: If you work with Hibernate, you could make use of the additional HQL functions: `extract( DAY from current_date )`