# How to get the database time with JPQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpql

with native SQL I get the database time with a statement like:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

with JPQL I get the same result with:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM Customer c
WHERE c.id=1
```

Is there a way to get rid of the last two lines?

thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain CURDATE() / NOW() on a JPA named query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500397/how-to-obtain-curdate-now-on-a-jpa-named-query)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [JSR 220: Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=220) specifications:

> ### 4.6.16 Functional Expressions
>
> The Java Persistence query language
>   includes the following built-in
>   functions, **which may be used in the
>   WHERE or HAVING clause of a query**.
>
> If the value of any argument to a
>   functional expression is null or
>   unknown, the value of the functional
>   expression is unknown.
>
> [...]
>
> **4.6.16.3 Datetime Functions**
>
> ```
> functions_returning_datetime:=
>              CURRENT_DATE |
>              CURRENT_TIME |
>              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> ```
>
> The datetime functions return the
>   value of current date, time, and
>   timestamp on the database server.

So I'm already surprised you can write the 2nd form that is not correct per specification and might thus not be portable.

To me, the "right" way to do this would be to create a class with a date field of type `java.util.Date` and to populate it with a native query. Something like that:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class DateItem {
    private Date date;

    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATE_VALUE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param date
     *            the date to set
     */
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

/**
 * @return System date on DB server
 */
public Date getSystemDate() {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", DateItem.class);
    DateItem dateItem = (DateItem) query.getSingleResult();
    return dateItem.getDate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Q: Is `DATE_VALUE` column name also specified?

Comment: With JPA 2.1, this only worked for me with `"SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE_VALUE FROM DUAL"`. With the above mentioned query JPA complained that the FROM keyword is missing. Did this work in previous versions?

Answer (score 1):

For java 8, one would update `Date` to `Instant`, so I changed @Pascal's code to:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class DateItem {
    private Instant date;

    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATE_VALUE")
    public Instant getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param date
     *            the date to set
     */
    public void setDate(Instant date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
/**
 * @return System date on DB server
 */
public Instant getSystemDate() {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE_VALUE", DateItem.class);
    DateItem dateItem = (DateItem) query.getSingleResult();
    return dateItem.getDate();
}
```

Note: The `SELECT` is changed as pointed by @Dominic to make it work. However, `"SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE_VALUE FROM DUAL"`will work for H2 but not postgres. `"SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE_VALUE"` works for both H2 and postgres "on my system"(TM)