# How to map timestamp column to JPA type?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, playframework

I'm using Play! 1.2.4 and PostgreSQL 9.1.  I created a table with a `created_at` column, of type: `timestamp without time zone`.  It has a default value of `now()`.

The problem comes when I fetch data using my Entity class for this table. The `createdAt` field is always coming back `null`. Here is the field definition:

```
@Column(name="created_at", insertable=false)
public java.sql.Date createdAt;
```

All the other fields are populated correctly. I have tried changing the field type to a `Date`, `Calendar`, `Timestamp`, etc., and tried adding a `@Timestamp` annotation. But no combination has proved successful.

Thanks in advance for any help!

For reference, here is the DDL I used to create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
  id serial     NOT NULL,
  username text NOT NULL,
  email text    NOT NULL,
  password_hash text NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT Users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT Users_username_key UNIQUE (username)
);
```

**Update:**
I think the problem has to do with using JPA to insert a record. The database populates a default value of `now()` for `created_at`, but somehow Hibernate doesn't know about it when fetching that row.

If I query for a row that already existed, the `createdAt` field is populated correctly!
OK... this narrows down the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I didn't solve the problem exactly, but I worked around it.

Instead of having the database supply the default value of `now()`, I expressed it in JPA with `@PrePersist`:

```
@Column(name="created_at", nullable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date createdAt;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    createdAt = new Date();
}
```

That works fine!  Inspiration taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8207652/187145).
I'm still not sure why Hibernate didn't get updated with the default value that was applied in the database.  It was stuck thinking the value was still null.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@Column(name="create_at", insertable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createAt;
```

Comment: I tried it, but no go.  The field is still coming back null from the database.

Comment: Try this then `@Column(name="create_at", insertable=false, nullable=false)`

Comment: How is your query? or try this too: `@Column(name="create_at", insertable=false, columnDefinition = "now()")`

Comment: The table is already defined in the database. I'm not using JPA DDL to create it at runtime.
I can use JPA to insert a row and `created_at` is automatically set to now() in the database. But when I fetch the row, all of the fields are present, except the createdAt field is null.  Somehow the `timestamap` database value is not being converted.

Comment: Read this http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/TemporalTypeTIMESTAMP.htm use the `java.util.Date` or  `java.util.Calendar`. Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Turned out the problem was more with Hibernate not noticing that the database had supplied a value for `created_at`... I'm still not sure how to get it to notice that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detach and fetch entity from db. Insert statement does not contain created_at field so it's not managed by JPA at the time of creation. In repository it would look like this:

```
@Transactional
public Log save(Log log) {
    this.em.persist(log);
    this.em.detach(log);
    return this.em.find(Log.class, log.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if the class where you fill the field definition is a master class, which all the other class extends it, don't forget to define it with the annotation:

```java
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class MySuperClass {}
```