# Spring JPA using database timestamp for inserts

Tags: spring, jpa

I am using Spring JPA

```
@Column(name = "rec_cren_tm", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Timestamp recCrenTm;
```

which is using database timestamp and inserting properly.

But while fetching I am getting this is property as null. Below is what I am using on the method

```
@Transactional
public interface IClaimRepository extends JpaRepository<Claim, Long> {
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    List<Claim> findByLnId(String LnId);
```

How do I get this?

Comment: you need to add more information. e.g. how Claim entity looks like, how you use your repository. maybe it is null because it is null in a database for the record you fetch ?

Comment: any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer i am looking for [How to map timestamp column to JPA type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528439/how-to-map-timestamp-column-to-jpa-type)

But this thread doesnt have solution i am looking for