# Using current time in UTC as default value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

I have a column of the `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` type and would like to have that default to the current time in UTC. Getting the current time in UTC is easy:

```
postgres=# select now() at time zone 'utc';
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2013-05-17 12:52:51.337466
(1 row)
```

As is using the current timestamp for a column:

```
postgres=# create temporary table test(id int, ts timestamp without time zone default current_timestamp);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into test values (1) returning ts;
             ts             
----------------------------
 2013-05-17 14:54:33.072725
(1 row)
```

But that uses local time. Trying to force that to UTC results in a syntax error:

```
postgres=# create temporary table test(id int, ts timestamp without time zone default now() at time zone 'utc');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "at"
LINE 1: ...int, ts timestamp without time zone default now() at time zo...
```

Answer (score 436, accepted):

A function is not even needed. Just put parentheses around the default expression:

```
create temporary table test(
    id int, 
    ts1 timestamp default (now() at time zone 'utc')
    -- alternative syntax
    ts2 timestamp default (timezone('utc', now())),
);
```

> NOTE: The SQL standard requires that writing just timestamp be equivalent to timestamp without time zone, and PostgreSQL honors that behavior. timestamptz is accepted as an abbreviation for timestamp with time zone; this is a PostgreSQL extension.
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I can see a funciton like now_utc() really shines when writing queries

Comment: This even works when the time goes back an hour -- now() returns a timestamp that knows the offset from UTC.

Comment: FWIW, running this query in PostgreSQL 11.5: `ALTER TABLE testcase_result ADD COLUMN date_created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE "UTC") NOT NULL;` fails with: `ERROR:  column "UTC" does not exist`. ***Make sure `'utc'` is all lower-case.***

Comment: Correction: The `'utc'` string must also be single-quoted, not double-quoted.

Comment: For expiration dates you can add to the current time: `timestamp without time zone default ((now() + '5 days') at time zone 'utc')`

Answer (score 145):

Still another solution:

```
timezone('utc', now())
```

Answer (score 40):

Wrap it in a function:

```
create function now_utc() returns timestamp as $$
  select now() at time zone 'utc';
$$ language sql;

create temporary table test(
  id int,
  ts timestamp without time zone default now_utc()
);
```

Answer (score 22):

What about

```
now()::timestamp
```

If your other timestamp are without time zone then this cast will yield the matching type "timestamp without time zone" for the current time.

I would like to read what others think about that option, though. I still don't trust in my understanding of this "with/without" time zone stuff.

EDIT:
Adding Michael Ekoka's comment here because it clarifies an important point:

> Caveat. The question is about generating default timestamp in UTC for
>   a timestamp column that happens to not store the time zone (perhaps
>   because there's no need to store the time zone if you know that all
>   your timestamps share the same). What your solution does is to
>   generate a local timestamp (which for most people will not necessarily
>   be set to UTC) and store it as a naive timestamp (one that does not
>   specify its time zone).

Comment: It's an interesting trick but it can lead to confusion unless you are aware of this behavior. The accepted answer is crystal clear on the action and result desired. Same with the function but I stay away from functions in DBs....

Comment: in my option it generates local datetime into db

Comment: Caveat. The question is about *generating default timestamp in UTC* for a timestamp column that happens to not store the time zone (perhaps because there's no need to store the time zone if you know that all your timestamps share the same). What your solution does is to generate a *local timestamp* (which for most people will not necessarily be set to UTC) and store it as a naive timestamp (one that does not specify its time zone).

Comment: @MichaelEkoka I have added your comment into the answer - please go ahead and edit it if you want. You're explaining it very clearly. Thanks!

Comment: **Warning**: a timestamp with time zone field does NOT store the time zone, contrary to reasonable assumption. See the below link and search the page for UTC. On input, a timestamp with time zone converts the incoming value to utc and stores that value **WITH NO TIME ZONE OR OFFSET INFORMATION**. On output, the stored utc value is converted to a local time using time zone of the client if available.  This type is all about value conversion at query time. You should test this by storing from one time zone and selecting from a different one.  

postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 15):

#### These are 2 equivalent solutions:

(in the following code, you should substitute `'UTC'` for **zone** and `now()` for **timestamp**)

1. `timestamp AT TIME ZONE zone` - SQL-standard-conforming
2. `timezone(zone, timestamp)` - arguably more readable

> The function timezone(zone, timestamp) is equivalent to the SQL-conforming construct timestamp AT TIME ZONE zone.

---

#### Explanation:

- **zone** can be specified either as a text string (e.g., `'UTC'`) or as an interval (e.g., `INTERVAL '-08:00'`) - here is a list of [all available time zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/timezones.html)
- **timestamp** can be any value of type *timestamp*
- `now()` returns a value of type **timestamp** (just what we need) with your database's default time zone attached (e.g. `2018-11-11T12:07:22.3+05:00`).
- `timezone('UTC', now())` turns our current time (of type **timestamp with time zone**) into the timezonless equivalent in `UTC`.
  E.g., `SELECT timestamp with time zone '2020-03-16 15:00:00-05' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` will return `2020-03-16T20:00:00Z`.

Docs: [timezone()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)

Comment: Thank's for summarizing these things.  I used lowercase version `at timezone 'utc'` and that doesn't worked with my PostgreSQL setup.  Using uppercase letters solved issue

Answer (score 4):

Function already exists:
timezone('UTC'::text, now())