# PostgreSQL: insert sql statement with default timestamp - dbeaver vs php

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, dbeaver, sql-timestamp

Given this simple table:

```
create table comments (
  id numeric not null,
  comment text, 
  created timestamp not null default now()
);
```

Using dbeaver directly on the db from my pc, and executing this statement

```
insert into comments (id, comment)
select 1111, 'test';
```

the "created" field of the new record is: `2017-02-24 16:17:21`
and that's my correct time (CET).

When I run the very same statement from a php script (running on a linux-based webserver connected to the db), the result is `2017-02-24 15:17:21`.
The linux server time is ok (that is, CET).

What am I missing?

Comment: In your PHP ini file, check the selected timezone. EDIT: Actually not quite sure why this would matter

Comment: Sounds like you're missing about an hour

Comment: @pteronewone that was a good one :)

Comment: @Andy I already tried to set date_default_timezone_set('CET');

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609724/using-current-time-in-utc-as-default-value-in-postgresql

Comment: @Andy default (now() at time zone ('CET')) worked like a charm.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609724/using-current-time-in-utc-as-default-value-in-postgresql), change your table definition to

```
create table comments (
   id numeric not null,
   comment text, 
   created timestamp not null default (now() at time zone ('CET'))
);
```

which will use the current datetime using the desired time zone.