# Skip a column on INSERT with JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have a JPA/EclipseLink model with multiple parameters whose values are set as defaults by the PostgreSQL database. Specifically, I have:

- An `id` column of type `SERIAL` which auto-increments when new rows are added
- A `created_at` column of type `TIMESTAMP` which defaults to `now()`

My model looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="entity")
@NamedQuery(name="Entity.findAll", query="SELECT e from Entity e")
public class Entity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="created_at")
    private java.sql.Timestamp createdAt;

    // constructor, getters, and setters
}
```

When I try to insert a row with `persist()` in `javax.persistence.EntityManager`, the insertion fails because a `NULL` value is being set for the `created_at` column. Rather than inserting `NULL`, I want to simply not insert anything into that column and allow PostgreSQL to set it to `now()`.  Essentially, I would like to use `@GeneratedValue` on `createdAt`, but that annotation is only for primary keys and cannot be used on multiple attributes. Is there another annotation I can use that will accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202154/how-to-create-an-auto-generated-date-timestamp-field-in-a-play-jpa

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want `insertable=false` in the `Column` annotation:

```
@Column(name="created_at", insertable=false)
private java.sql.Timestamp createdAt;
```

From: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html

> boolean insertable 
>             (Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provide

Answer (score 3):

You can add `@DynamicInsert` on your entity class. The insert statement will include null fields when without this annotation. Also, you can add `@ DynamicUpdate` when executing the update statement.

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name="entity")
@NamedQuery(name="Entity.findAll", query="SELECT e from Entity e")
public class Entity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="created_at")
    private java.sql.Timestamp createdAt;

    // constructor, getters, and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, JPA providers will set the value on insert if you have it marked as insertable=true (the default).  This occurs with many providers even if null as it allows statement reuse.

Just excluding it from the statement though might not be what you want, as to have the value in your entity (and in the cache) will require refreshing.  EclipseLink though has [@ReturningInsert](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_returninsert.htm) which allows EclipseLink to update the entity with the value in the database.  Unfortunately support is only for Oracle - other databases require use of stored procedures to return run the insert and return the value.