# What is the best way to query a JPA entity for instances based on the current date+time?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity type that has two dates, startDate and endDate:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@Entity
public class Thing {
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime startDate;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime endtDate;
}
```

I have a Spring Data-JPA repository (extends `CrudRepository`) for this entity type, and in there I need a way to query for all `Thing`s that are "active" where "active" is defined as

*startDate <= now <= endDate*

I tried a JPQL query like this, but it's not producing the expected results in some of our tests:

```
@Query("select t from Thing t where t.startDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and t.endDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
public Iterable<Thing> findAllActive();
```

---

I also tried a method-name-convention query, which does produce the results I expect, but it's awkward:

```
public Iterable<Thing> findByStartDateBeforeAndEndDateAfter(DateTime minStartDate, DateTime maxEndDate);
```

I can wrap that in my `@Service` like

```
public Iterable<Thing> getActiveThings() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    return repository.findByStartDateBeforeAndEndDateAfter(now, now);
}
```

So the service interface is clean, but the repo interface is ugly and awkward (in my opinion).

Is there a better way to construct this Repository query method using JPA, either a better method-name-based query or an explicit JPQL query? I'd prefer to not have to manually construct the Query object in code (right now I don't even have a concrete class for the Repository, only an interface), but if that's the best way I'll consider it.

Comment: what is the value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a built-in function in JPQL that returns the current date+time on the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1659088/639520

Comment: I've written JPQL query which involves date comparison which works fine but I was using Default `Date` type unlike the type you specified. Try using `java.util.Date` to see if `@Type` is causing problem.

Comment: First, check what the JPQL is converted to and verify that the storage can handle comparisons using the date type you've picked.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect, we're not changing the entities to use java.util.Date,  Joda Time library is much more functional and we've already based logic in the app on it. I know it supports comparisons because the method-name version works (it's just ugly).

Comment: @Chris, the Joda DateTime is stored as a timestamp in the DB (at least for MySQL and H2 it is). Like I said, Spring-generated query based on method name works as expected, so I know the type works for comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply have the following:

```
@Query("select t from Thing t where t.startDate <= :time and t.endDate >= :time")
public Iterable<Thing> findActiveThings(@Param("time") DateTime time);
```

Which has the advantage of using only 1 parameter , but also allows you to later have queries such as: "Give me the list of active things on January 24th 2011"

Answer (score 0):

You can write a workaround, something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Thing t WHERE t.startDate <= :maxStartDate AND :minEndDate <= t.endDate")
public Iterable<Thing> findAllActive();
```

And create `DateTime maxStartDate` and `DateTime minEndDate` which are e.g. `2015-01-01 00:00:00` and `2015-01-01 23:59:59`

```
DateTime maxStartDate= new DateTime().withTime(23, 59, 59, 0);
DateTime minEndDate = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```