# How to select every record from one month from a table in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

is there a clean way to get every record from one month in a table with a column that contains dates from several months in JPA createQuery?

This is what i have now. But this is with the whole date field. I need to get the month of that date.

```
public List<DayData> findAllDataForUser(String username, Date date)
    {
        return em.createQuery("select d from DayData d where d.name = :username and d.ramDate = :date")
                .setParameter("username", username)
.setParameter("date", date)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: Is the problem about the query in general, the condition being on dates data or everything ? Because I am not sure on what I should focus for the answer. You should show use what you have tried so far to correct it.

Comment: I have a table with name of user, date and a projectname. The date column contains all the dates of every month. I show every date of one month on my jsf page. So i need to get the data from the table for the current month at basis of the current date. So the focus is on the date where i need to get the month of that date to get all dates in de table from that month

Comment: Yes. Post what you have tried ... and JPA does not use TABLES and COLUMNS. It uses CLASSES and FIELDS

Comment: I have edit my question to add what i have now for code

Answer (score 0):

You can use like.

```
.createQuery("SELECT s from table s WHERE s.date_created BETWEEN 
     (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()");
```

Comment: Something like this?

public List<DayData> findAllDataForUser(String username)
{
    return em.createQuery("select d from DayData d where d.name = :username 
            and d.ramDate BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()")
            .setParameter("username", username)
            .getResultList();
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA's `@Query`

`@Query(value = "SELECT s from table s WHERE s.data_created <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

Comment: This _may_ work, but `CURDATE()` is not platform independent. There are [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500397/how-to-obtain-curdate-now-on-a-jpa-named-query) which are not dependent on platform.